# Postman Returning Empty when using GET request

Tags: javascript, mongodb, api

I am working on a RESTful API using mongodb, js, express and postman to test it. I am trying to connect to my cloud atlas mongodb cluster and retrieve all the information. However, when testing it on postman, it returns empty: []

I can connect to the database just fine and I have 3 documents in my collection. The name of the database is mobile_phone_store and the collection is called personal_information

here is my server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const infoRoute = require("./app/routes/db.routes.js");

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

mongoose.connect(
"mongodb+srv://*************************/mobile_phone_store?retryWrites=true&w=majority", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  }
);

app.use(infoRoute);

app.listen(3000, () => {
console.log("Server is running...");
});
```

here is my db.model.js

```
  const mongoose = require('mongoose');
 // create a mongoose schema for a quotation
const PersonalInfoSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    customerID: String,
    Title: String,
    Fname: String,
    Lname: String,
    mobile: String,
    email: String
},     {

    timestamps: true
});
 // export the model to our app

 const personal_information = mongoose.model("personal_information", PersonalInfoSchema);

 module.exports = personal_information;
```

here is my db.routes

```
  const express = require("express");
  const Model = require("../models/db.model");
  const app = express();

 app.get("/personal_informations", async(request, response) => {
     const infos = await Model.find({});

     try {
         response.send(infos);
    } catch (error) {
         response.status(500).send(error);
    }
    });

 module.exports = app;
```

In postman I am using the url http://localhost:3000/personal_informations. Any Ideas? I have been searching for an solution for a while now and Im not finding anything

Comment: what's the status you see in the response? try logging `infos` before sending the response

Comment: when i try console.log(infos); it also returns []

Comment: try putting the const infos = await... line inside try block

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be with the MongoDB connection.

Try this to listen when the `connect` resolves:

```
mongoose
  .connect(
    'mongodb+srv://*************************/mobile_phone_store?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
    {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useFindAndModify: false,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    }
  )
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(3000, () => {
      console.log('Server is running...');
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Okay that made some progress, however now postman returns an error saying it cannot get personal _informations ie:       
<pre>Cannot GET /personal_informations</pre>

Comment: It connects to the database just fine btw

Comment: @tinaburner try placing `app.get("/personal_informations"...` in the server.js before the connect snippet

Comment: it still returns []

Comment: @tinaburner make sure that the collection has documents and try sending a test response like `response.send('test');`

Comment: looks like there is an issue sending. I tried to send `respone.send('testing')` and the same error happened. My collection 100% has documents. Im very perplexed